# Create a regular expression for deleting whitespaces after a newline in python

Tags: python, regex, removing-whitespace

I'd like to know how to create a regular expression to delete whitespaces after a newline, for example, if my text is like this:

```
So she refused to ex-
       change the feather and the rock be-
       cause she was afraid.
```

how I can create something to get:

```
["so","she","refused","to","exchange", "the","feather","and","the","rock","because","she","was","afraid" ]
```

i've tried to use "replace("-\n","")" to try to get them together but i only get something like:

["be","cause"] and ["ex","change"]

Any suggestion? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

s = '''So she refused to ex-
       change the feather and the rock be-
       cause she was afraid.'''.lower()

s = re.sub(r'-\n\s*', '', s)   # join hyphens
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)  # remove punctuation

print(s.split())
```

`\s*` means 0 or more spaces.

Comment: And what happend if the hypen is in a different encoding? I tried to use your code with a text that was given to me and when i see the print it gives me a "\xad"

Comment: @john replace `-` with `[-\xad]`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, Alex Hall's answer more adequately answers your question (both explicitly in that it's regex and implicitly in that it's adjusts capitalization and removes punctuation), but it jumped out as a good candidate for a generator.

Here, using a generator to join tokens popped from a stack-like list:

```
s = '''So she refused to ex-
       change the feather and the rock be-
       cause she was afraid.'''


def condense(lst):
    while lst:
        tok = lst.pop(0)
        if tok.endswith('-'):
            yield tok[:-1] + lst.pop(0)
        else:
            yield tok


print(list(condense(s.split())))

# Result:
# ['So', 'she', 'refused', 'to', 'exchange', 'the', 'feather', 
#  'and', 'the', 'rock', 'because', 'she', 'was', 'afraid.']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s.replace('-\n', '') #Replace the newline and - with a space

#Your s would now look like 'So she refused to ex       change the feather and the rock be       cause she was afraid.'

s = re.sub('\s\s+', '', s) #Replace 2 or more whitespaces with a ''

#Now your s would look like 'So she refused to exchange the feather and the rock because she was afraid.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optional greedy expression:

```
-?\n\s+
```

This needs to be replaced by nothing, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lbfOGA/1/).
For the second part, I'd suggest `nltk` so that you end up having:

```
import re
from nltk import word_tokenize

string = """
So she refused to ex-
       change the feather and the rock be-
       cause she was afraid.
"""

rx = re.compile(r'-?\n\s+')
words = word_tokenize(rx.sub('', string))
print(words)
# ['So', 'she', 'refused', 'to', 'exchange', 'the', 'feather', 'and', 'the', 'rock', 'because', 'she', 'was', 'afraid', '.']
```